# Issue with Xdebug with Netbeans and Zend framework 

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

Trying to debug my web site, I hit "Debug Project", get a browser window opened up, and the debugger stops at the first line of the index.php file (which is the root document).
Pushing Continue always stops at the same line.
It seems that every Get or Post is causing the debugger to stop there and I have to push Continue multiple times to get the site to show anything.
I did not place any breakpoint on index.php.

Another thing is that all images are missing from the browser that shows the debuged site.

Thanks!
Avi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, that's a configurable thing. Some people like it. I find it as annoying as you do. Do this:

- Click on *Tools*, then *Options*, and then on the *PHP* icon in the option dialog's toolbar.
- Make sure the *General* tab is selected.
- In the *Debugging* section, un-check *"Stop at first line"*

That should set it to continue until it hits a breakpoint that you explicitly set.  Re-check it if you are having issues before the first line of project code is executed, so you can see the initial state before execution.

For your second issue, I don't remember ever seeing something like that. It sounds like something on the server side is possibly not configured properly? *Maybe* something about the run configuration is not set right?  To look at the run configuration:

- Right-click on the top-most project node in the *Projects* tab over on the left.
- Click on *Properties*
- Choose *Run Configuration* under *Categories*.

As an example, my PHP project is *Run As* a *Remote Web Site*; the *Project URL* is *`http://www.example.com/`* (yours will point to your test server, maybe localhost?); the *Index File* is *`src/index.php`* because my project is run from the /src subdirectory on the server (to match the fact that our version control has the main directory of the source code under /src); I don't need any *Arguments*.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. 
The first problem is resolved. 
Regarding the missing images, it looks like Apache is not obeying the .htaccess file when on debug mode, and runs Zend index.php in spite the file to be fetched is of type .jpg (my .htaccess has RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf)$ index.php).
Any idea why that could happen?

Comment: `RewriteRule !.+\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf)$ index.php` you need the filename part in the rule.  `.+` is "one or more of any char"

Comment: actually, what you had should have worked too, since you didn't have `!^`. But give the other suggestion a try

Comment: By the way, to see what mod_rewrite is thinking do `RewriteLog /path/to/rewrite.log` and `RewriteLogLevel 3` (or 2 or 4). Just remember to set RewriteLogLevel back to 0 when you whip mod_rewrite into shape. Rewrite logging can seriously slow things down.

Comment: As you've guessed, your new rewriterule format did not help )-:
I tried to do the logging, but got a "RewriteLogLevel not allowed here" on apache_error file.
Can it be that the RewriteRule needs to include extra set of characters after the jpg and png as the URL on debug mode contains extra characters at the end?

Comment: RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel have to go into httpd.conf (or extras/httpd-vhost.conf if a virtual server) (or where ever you have your conf files).

Comment: From the RewriteRule docs... _"The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string"_, so no, it should stop at the end of the file extension.

Comment: Did you get something to work? If it was not really this answer, then you can post the proper answer and accept that. If it was this answer, just with some tweaks, let me know what to tweak.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I made some nice progress thanks to the log. I found that the issue is caused by the way Zend calculates $baseurl. On debug mode, $baseurl is wrongly containing index.php ("/coachya/http/index.php"), which then effects all the links on the view scripts

Comment: the cause of this is $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI'] which is set to:/coachya/http/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug and causing Zend_Controller_Request_Http.setBaseUrl() to come up with this value.
Trying to trick the code into having $baseurl be set correctly, caused the code to break at the dispatcher (isDispatchable fails), as it miscalculated the target controller class name.
I think the problem lies somewhere in a more basic level. Maybe the Apache httpd file or php.ini or some Zend configuration. Any ideas are welcomed to solve this mystery ;-)

Comment: I found the issue. Changing the netbeans project settings "Index file" to: http/ instead of http/index.php solved it. Strange as this field lets you browse to your index file. 
Anyway thanks for the good advise! This was a learning experience for me.